# Laravel populate data on redirect route

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I'm doing a error exception where display a modal popup when fail to delete an entry due to parent constrain

Controller :

```
public function deleteUnitType(Request $request, $proj_id)
    {
        $id = $request->id;
        $unit_types = UnitType::where('id', $id);
        $floors = UnitTypeFloor::where('unit_type_id', $id)->get();
        if(count($floors) != 0){
            return redirect()->route('dev-admin.projects.unit-types.index', ['unit_types' => $unit_types, 'proj_id' => $proj_id, 'floors' => $floors])->with('failed', 'Unit Type failed to delete due to existing floor plan.');
        } else {
            // $unit_types->delete();
            return redirect()->route('dev-admin.projects.unit-types.index', ['unit_types' => $unit_types, 'proj_id' => $proj_id])->with('status', 'Unit Type is successfully deleted.');
        }
    }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="col-12">
    @if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        {{ session('status') }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    @elseif (session('failed'))
    <div class="modal fade" id="unit-type-notification-modal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>{{ session('failed') }}</p>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach($floors as $floor)
                            <li>{{ $floor -> name }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
</div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
        @if (session('failed'))
            $('#unit-type-notification-modal').modal('show');
        @endif

    });
```

The modal popup and everything but for some reason it cannot find my `$floor` variable, it says :

> Undefined variable: floors

but when I dd it on my controller, the data exist

Answer (score 0):

**I think you should check the first session has 'failed' following way.**

```
@if(Session::has('status'))

@elseif( Session::has( 'failed' ) )
```

And your script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    @if(Session::has('failed'))
        $('#unit-type-notification-modal').modal('show');
    @endif

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I still have the same error, `@if (session('failed'))` this code work if i remove the `$floor`

Comment: @M.Izzat  Your modal is hidden right. When clicking on `unit-type-notification-modal` then `$floors` not found. Please explain..

Comment: its hidden but on document ready i make it automatically displayed. even if its hidden it shouldnt be a problem

Comment: @M.Izzat So can you change `if($floors->count() != 0){` in your controller file. I think if condtion through false. And that is why `floors` Not found.
First, print your '$floors' array inside `if condition` and check data is coming..

Answer (score 0):

You can add another with to your redirect route

```
return redirect()->route('dev-admin.projects.unit-types.index', ['unit_types' => $unit_types, 'proj_id' => $proj_id, 'floors' => $floors])
->with('failed', 'Unit Type failed to delete due to existing floor plan.')
->with('floors', $floors);
```

Or this;

```
return redirect()->route('dev-admin.projects.unit-types.index', ['unit_types' => $unit_types, 'proj_id' => $proj_id, 'floors' => $floors])
    ->with(['failed' => 'Unit Type failed to delete due to existing floor plan.', 'floors' => $floors]);
```

Comment: @M.Izzat use session('floors')